# Реализация рекурсивного метода в классах с++

Tags: c++, классы, сортировка

Есть класс, который отвечает за сортировку быструю. Так вот, ка реализовать данный кусок(рекурсию) для класса, не могу этого понять

```
  /* recursion */
    if (left < j)
    fast(N, left, j);
    if (i < right)
    fast(N, i, right);
```

Вот сам класс

```
class fast {
private:
    int* N;
    int index;
    int left;
    int right;

public:
    fast(int k)
    {
        index = k;
        left = 0;
        right = index - 1;
        N = new int[index];
    }
    ~fast()
    {

        delete[] N;
    }
    void vvod()
    {
        srand(time(NULL));
        for (int r = 0; r < index; r++) {
            N[r] = rand() % 10000 + 1;
        }
    }
    void vivod()
    {
        for (int g = 0; g < index; g++) {
            cout << N[g] << " " << endl;
        }
    }
    void sortirovka(int N, int left, int right)
    {
        int i = left, j = right;
        int tmp;
        int pivot = N[(left + right) / 2];

        /* partition */
        while (i <= j) {
            while (N[i] < pivot)
                i++;
            while (N[j] > pivot)
                j--;
            if (i <= j) {
                tmp = N[i];
                N[i] = N[j];
                N[j] = tmp;
                i++;
                j--;
            }
        };

        /* recursion */
        if (left < j)
            fast(N, left, j);
        if (i < right)
            fast(N, i, right);
    }
};
```

Comment: "Рекурсия для класса" - это не верно. Рекурсией называется вызов из процедуры самой себя.

Comment: @nick_n_a как тогда возможно реализовать сортировку которая использует рекурсию в классах?

Comment: Вы просто вызываете конструктор класса и все, это ничего не дает, кроме, в вашем случае, утечек памяти. Как отметил nick_n_a, рекурсия - это вызов функции из самой себя. В вашем случае в классе нужно сделать метод, который будет вызывать сам себя с нужными параметрами. Только не забудьте условие выхода из функции.